# How do I store values to create an average in GML

Tags: loops, while-loop, average, game-engine, gml

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I tried google and stackoverflow but I couldn't find anything.

So, I want my end user to be able to enter an unspecified amount of number values and then I want my program to create an average number out of the values entered.

If I was able to restrict the amount of values entered I would just use multiple variables but because it's unrestricted I'm using a while loop that closes itself when the user enters 0.

```
var userinput;
userinput=1;
while(userinput>0)
{
    userinput = get_integer("Please input values","")
}
show_message(userinput);
end_game();
```

I don't even know if this is possible but if I could just find a way to list the values entered I'd be able to make the averages and finish this.

EDIT: I solved this myself it was a silly question to ask. Incase anyone googled this and ended up here I made three new variables.

I made a total variable, average variable and number of inputs variable.

`userinput = get_integer("Please input values")
 total = total + userinput
 numofinputs = numofinputs + 1`

Then subtract what ever you need to at the end and print the average.

Comment: Feel free to put your solution in an answer and accept it.